# For loop assistance + accumulation

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I'm very new to programming (so I apologize in advance), and I am having trouble figuring out how to make a for loop that will do the following:

I'm asking the user to input two variables (i'll call them x & y), which I then am calculating x/y = z. I want to pose this two variable input question 3 times, and then add up the 3 z to find the average. (The later part about accumulating/averaging I can figure out, but getting a for loop to repeat and give z three times is stumping my extremely novice mind. So far I can only get the for loop to ask for the two variable inputs one time, spit out z, and then terminate (I haven't attempted the averaging of z yet, because I don't have more than one z at this time).

To make things clearer, here's what I've got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

    float x, y, z;
    int c;

    printf ("Enter x: ");
    scanf ("%f", &x);
    while ( (c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);

    printf ("Enter y: ");
    scanf ("%f", &y);
    while ( (c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);

    for (; x <3; x++)
    {
        z = x / y;
        printf("Your average is %f\n", z);
    }

    printf("Thank you for using the program. Goodbye\n" );

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: If I understood correctly what you're asking, just move the request for `x` and `y` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Aside: `char c;` should be `int c;` - please read the man page for `getchar()`. And note too, that `%f` input format filters out leading whitespace, so is not even necessary. The problem comes if you use `"%c"` format and with that you can force `scanf` to ignore leading whitespace with `" %c"` note the space before the %.

Comment: You probably also want to make a separate variable for iterating through the loop instead of using x to assign and loop, as well as make said iteration variable an integer.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean for iterating through the loop? Also I made your other changes, and it still only prompts me for x and y one time (instead of 3 separate times), and it outputs the average of x & y two times (building on the initial input). (I edited the code above to reflect the changeS)

Comment: Since your variable `x` is being used to assign a value, and it is also being used to iterate through your for loop, if the person enters 3 for the value of `x`, it will exit your loop immediately, and if they keep typing something less than 3 it could potentially never exit the loop. You basically need a 4th variable(as in krisz's answer).

Comment: If you would like to implement it without float, try (x+5)/y = z

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float z[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        float x, y;

        printf ("Enter x: ");
        scanf ("%f", &x);

        printf ("Enter y: ");
        scanf ("%f", &y);

        z[i] = x / y;

        printf("Your average is %f\n", z[i]);
    }

    printf("Your overall average is %f\n", (z[0] + z[1] + z[2]) / 3);

    printf("Thank you for using the program. Goodbye\n" );

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why all the extra newlines?

Comment: That's getting closer in that I'm prompted for x & y three times, but I want it to show the average after each prompt for x & y, and then after the 3rd time, show the overall average of all 3 prompts. Does that make sense?

Comment: Didn't want to change op's coding style

Comment: @JStruck krisz did all the rest for you, you really can't figure out how to make it print the z on each iteration through the loop? Did you attempt anything?

Comment: Trying :/   .... First time ever programming, so Its a new way of thinking. I did apologize in advance :P

Comment: @JStruck I have edited the code to meet your requirements

Comment: Thanks, I was actually close, I was trying printf("Your average is %f\n", z"); ... but that gave me a warning. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Does that -2 mean people are dinging my basically non-existant reputation? What's the point of help forums if people are irked to help...

Comment: I'm only asking because you are only going to learn by reading the errors and warnings you get, and figuring out why you got them and how to fix them. Having someone do your homework for you is quick and easy, but you won't learn how to debug your own code, let alone others code.

Comment: I get what you are saying, I agree.

Comment: @JS I didn't downvote, but having been a member of the site for a while, I'd venture a guess that it has less to do with your non-existant reputation and more to do with the fact that it looks like a homework problem you would like solved. If you would like to learn more about the site and its expectations, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)